# Class design in OOPS protected Internal c#

Tags: c#, oop, protected, internal

when we use protected internal any data member of any class then we know that data member can use in same assembly but i did not know that protected internal can be used from other assembly. from here i come to know [Have you ever seen design with reasonable usage of protected internal access modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875955/have-you-ever-seen-design-with-reasonable-usage-of-protected-internal-access-mod)

### code in assembly1

```
public class A
    {
        internal protected virtual void YoBusiness()
        {
            //do something
        }

        public void test() { }
    }


    class B
    { // not a derived class - just composites an instance of A
        public B()
        {
            A a = new A();
            a.YoBusiness(); // Thanks friend for the access! 
        }
    }


    class D : A
    {  // derived across assemblies
        internal protected override void YoBusiness()
        {
            // Hey thanks other guy, I can provide a new implementation. 
        }
    }
```

### code in assembly2

```
class C : A
    {  // derived across assemblies
        public C()
        {
            YoBusiness();
        }

        protected override void YoBusiness()
        {
            // Hey thanks other guy, I can provide a new implementation. 
        }
    }
```

i knew always that protected internal can be used in same assembly but today know and surprise that any class from other assembly also could override the method......how it is getting possible?

if i want that only the data member can be override or call from same assembly then what i need to do......please discuss. thanks

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. If you mark it `protected` then derived classes can access it. If you don't want that, don't mark it `protected`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have you ever seen design with reasonable usage of protected internal access modifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875955/have-you-ever-seen-design-with-reasonable-usage-of-protected-internal-access-mod)

Comment: +1: I have no idea why this question is down voted. I also do not see any benefit of protected internal and I was going to ask the same question to see how others use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `protected internal` should be read as "protected **or** internal" (i.e., visible to any class within the same assembly *or* any class derived from `A` regardless of its location), and not as "protected *and* internal".

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which the protected internal element is declared, and it must take place through an instance of the derived class type.

---

> i want that only the data member can be override or call from same assembly then what i need to do

Then just mark it as `internal` and `virtual`.

Comment: anyone can give a real life situation where people has to use protected internal. i search google lot for real life sample code and situation.

Comment: @Thomas, can you imagine a scenario when *either* `protected` *or* `internal` might be useful?  If so, then imagining a scenario where you want the benefits of both doesn't seem like much of a stretch.

Comment: can u tell me when people use protected internal for their class constructor?

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the method to be overridable or callable from the same assembly then just flag the method as `internal`.

You can find more information on C# access modifiers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).

For an example of why you might use `protected internal` lets assume we've got a base class called `Job` which you derive from in order to add some functionality. The framework that runs the job will give you a `Context` which has information on how the job should run. Only the framework can set this context, but the job should be able to access it. You could design your class like this:

```
abstract class Job
{
  public abstract void Run()

  protected internal Context RunContext{get; internal set}
}
```

Now, only your framework can set the context, as long as it's in the same assembly. Your derived classes can only get the context, assuming they're in a different assembly.

Comment: anyone can give a real life situation where people has to use protected internal. i search google lot for real life sample code and situation.

Comment: can u tell me when people use protected internal for their class constructor?

Answer (score 0):

`protected internal` does not mean what you (and many other developers including myself) think it does. It does not mean `protected` **and** `internal`, it means `protected` **or** `internal`.  With this knowledge we know that classes that subclass the `protected internal` member will have visibility for that member, a class in another assembly will not.  The member is also visible anywhere in the assembly it was declared, regardless of whether or not the class accessing the member sub-classed the original class.